Http request in python module
Hi I have to know clarification on my scenario
my aim is to get an output of a api let the api be
http://abcd.com/api/getapidetail?type[]='one'&status='ongoing'
this is the actual api
now my code goes like
params={'type[]':'one','status':'ongoing'}
data=......encode(params)#encoding the parameter
r=request('POST','http://abcd.com/api/getapidetail',body=data)
print(r)

http//abcd.com/api/getapidetail?type[]='one'&status='ongoing'
from this API we will get some data WRT the query parameter and my aim is to get that from the code
will this satisfy my expectation if there are any changes please help me out also I want to know if this can be done with the get method if yes give me that way too
thanks.

You should use requests.get() to make a GET request, with the parameters sent in the URL.
